# How to Recover From a Broken Package

Tags: package-management, dpkg, dependencies

The Package system is broken

The message I get when trying to run the software updater is as follows:

> If you are using third party repositories then disable them, since
> they are a common source of problems. Now run the following command in
> a terminal: apt-get install -f Transaction failed: The package system
> is broken  The following packages have unmet dependencies:
>
> libc6-dbg: Depends: libc6 (= 2.27-3ubuntu1.4) but 2.27-3ubuntu1.3 is
> installed libc6-dev: Depends: libc6 (= 2.27-3ubuntu1.4) but
> 2.27-3ubuntu1.3 is installed
> Depends: libc-dev-bin (= 2.27-3ubuntu1.4) but 2.27-3ubuntu1.4 is installed

I disabled all third party repositories and ran the command:

```
Sudo apt-get install -f
```

and I got:

> debconf: DbDriver "config": /var/cache/debconf/config.dat is locked by
> another process: Resource temporarily unavailable (Reading database
> ... 310312 files and directories currently installed.) Preparing to
> unpack .../libc6_2.27-3ubuntu1.4_amd64.deb ... De-configuring
> libc6:i386 (2.27-3ubuntu1.3) ... debconf: DbDriver "config":
> /var/cache/debconf/config.dat is locked by another process: Resource
> temporarily unavailable dpkg: error processing archive
> /var/cache/apt/archives/libc6_2.27-3ubuntu1.4_amd64.deb (--unpack):
> new libc6:amd64 package pre-installation script subprocess returned
> error exit status 1 Preparing to unpack
> .../libc6_2.27-3ubuntu1.4_i386.deb ... De-configuring libc6:amd64
> (2.27-3ubuntu1.3) ... debconf: DbDriver "config":
> /var/cache/debconf/config.dat is locked by another process: Resource
> temporarily unavailable dpkg: error processing archive
> /var/cache/apt/archives/libc6_2.27-3ubuntu1.4_i386.deb (--unpack):
> new libc6:i386 package pre-installation script subprocess returned
> error exit status 1 Errors were encountered while processing:
> /var/cache/apt/archives/libc6_2.27-3ubuntu1.4_amd64.deb
> /var/cache/apt/archives/libc6_2.27-3ubuntu1.4_i386.deb E: Sub-process
> /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)

So I am stuck. How can I recover from this serious crash?
I am using Ubuntu 18.04.5 LTS

Many thanks

Comment: Yes! thank you very much user535733. It worked flawlessly. Do you know what may have caused this problem, so I avoid it in future? Thanks again

Comment: From one of the answers: "*There is a process still running, blocking debconf.*"